# Header won't show with video background:

Tags: html, css

I wanted to make a website with a header, but whenever I open the .html file, the header completely disappears:( Could anyone please help me! When I press the reload button the header appears, but then disappears, if that makes any sense...I'd really like to squash this problem, as the website's appeal is mainly based on its relatableness and layout, which isn't necessarily perfect, but on its way to being somewhat good.

```css
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
*{
box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
margin: 0;
font-family: Comic Sans, monospace;
font-size:12px;
}
#myVideo{
position: fixed;
right:;
bottom: 0;
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
}
#myBtn{
width: 200px;
font-size: 18px;
padding: 10px;
border: none;
background: black;
color: white;
curser: pointer;
}

#myBtn:hover{
background: white;
color: black;
}
.content{
position: relative;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
width: 100%;
padding:20px;
}
.topnav{
overflow: hidden;
display: block;
position:fixed;

}
.topnav a{
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
font-family:Comic Sans, monospace;
padding: 16px 32px;
float: left;
text-decoration: none;
color: white;
}
.topnav a:hover{
background-color: white;
color: grey;

}
.header{
background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
position:relative;
}
.card{
background-color: white;

}
</style>
</head>
</html>
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <h1>DaddyChill</h1>
        <div class="topnav">
<a href="kim.html">Home</a>
<a href="">About</a>
<a href="">Origin</a>
<a href="">Submit</a>
<a href="">Schools</a>
</div>
    </div>
<body>
<h1 style="color:grey; font-family: Comic Sans, monospace; font-size:70px;">DaddyChill</h1>

<br><br>
<video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo"><source src="Daddychill.mp4" type="video/mp4">Your browser does not support HTML5 video</video>
<br>
<br>
<div class="content">
<div class="card">
<p style="font-size: 25px">DaddyChill is the website that is here to help you become the student you were destined to be! Omumu started from the simple idea of wanting to share and distribute notesd to those who needed them the most. <br><br>We have all at some point in our high school career met that one person that always seemed to get the best marks.<br><br> There are two types of people in the world: the "Sean Camerons" and literally everyone else. DaddyChill hopes to help you become a Sean Cameron, or at least a you who isn't on life support for their grades! </p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looking to your html I see that you have two <body> tags. Maybe that's your problem.

Comment: Yeah, I see that now, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

As Filipe said, remove the body tag then add z-index to the video to return it behind:

```
<video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo" style="z-index: -1;"><source src="Daddychill.mp4" type="video/mp4">Your browser does not support HTML5 video</video>
```

Update: or add z-index to your css instead:

```
#myVideo{
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
z-index: -1;
}
```